# Inequality with Products and Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, products

I need help to find a proof for the following inquality.

Assuming that $ 0 \leq c_i \leq 1 $ and $ 0 \leq d_i \leq 1 $, show that
$$
\prod_{i=1}^N (c_i + d_i - c_i d_i) \geq \prod_{i=1}^N c_i + \prod_{i=1}^N d_i - \prod_{i=1}^N c_i d_i 
$$

This seems to have some relation with Weierstrass inequalities. This also looks like the outcome of using Jensen's inequality for composition of functions. However, the latter is not applicable as $ \prod_i c_i d_i $ is not convex. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's linear in each $c_i, d_i$ so the extremes occur at $ \{ 0, 1 \}^{2n}$.

Comment: Could you please give more details? You mean that Jensen's inequality can be applied?

Comment: Fix all of the terms other than $c_1$. Observe that the expression is linear in $c_1$, meaning it can be written as $ Ac_1 + B$ for some constants $A, B$. This achieves it's extrema at $ c_1 \in \{ 0 , 1 \}$ (possibly other points, but we don't care about that for now). $\quad$ Applying that argument to every term, we get that each of $c_i, d_i \in \{0, 1 \}$. So you just have to hunt down what happens then, which is much easier than $ c_1, d_i \in [0, 1 ] $. EG What can we say about the RHS?

Comment: No success thus far, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: Which part of the hint were you unable to push through? Can you show your working up till where you're stuck?